# Understanding backbone.js as a whole

Tags: backbone.js

**EDIT**: this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144365/highlighting-current-navigation-state-in-backbone-js-application) but it's more "conceptual" one.

Assume a single-page app with a bounce of static links that reflects `routes`:

```
<!-- Top navlist -->
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li><a class="active" href="#/customers">Customers</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Left navlist -->
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li><a class="active" href="#/customers">Show customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/customers/new">Create customer</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to set `class="active"` for one (or more) links based on the current route. Which is the correct approach?

1. Create `Link` and `LinkCollection` models, as long as `LinkCollectionView` and `LinkView`, from scratch: this seems overkill to me. And seems useless since links not depend upon server side (they are not dynamically created).
2. Create `Link` and `LinkCollection` models iterating over existing links.
3. Forget about models and view and manually set `class="active"` for each route. Something like `$('body').find('a[href="#/customers"]').addClass('active')`. Seems a duplication of code to me.
4. Create a "global" `AppView` view and do something like pt. 3 in `render()` funcion.

Routes definition example:

```
<script>
    (function($){
        var MyApp = { Models : {}, Collections : {}, Views : {} };

        // The Router
        MyApp.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes : {
                '/customers'     : 'showCustomersView',
                '/customers/new' : 'showCreateCustomerView'
            },
            showCustomersView      : function() {
               // Make customers links active
            },
            showCreateCustomerView : function() {
               // Make new customer links active
            },
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the "best practice", but I am fairly certain that involving models solely for the purpose of representing intra-app links is, as you said, definitely overkill and not their intended use.

I personally would do something like pattern #4. In a project I am currently working on, I have an AppView that looks a little something like this:

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click a.internal" : "handleLink"
  },

  handleLink: function (event) {
    var route = $(event.target).attr('data-route');
    router.navigate(route, true);
    return false;
  },

});
```

I do not use the actual `href` property on my anchor tags to specify the target route, as I am using pushState. Instead, I use an element class, `internal`, to indicate an anchor tag which is to be used for my app's internal navigation. I then use another arbitrary element attribute, `route`, to indicate where the link ought to be going.

A link might look like something like this, then:

`<a href="#" class="internal" data-route="projects/3">My Third Project</a>`

Adding in the extra bit to add that CSS class you want would then just be a matter of making a jQuery/Zepto call in `handleLink`.

Again, I don't necessarily believe this is a common/best practice, but at least for my purposes it seems to be sufficiently simplistic and straightforward (and also works with pushState).

**Edit**: Use steveax's suggestion of `data-route` for syntax validity sake.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. But i think that `router.navigate` is going to break the philosophy behind MVC pattern. It's the router that should retrieve data and serve the correct view. That's all it should do, IMHO.

Comment: Probably be better to use data-route, valid syntax that way.

Comment: Good call, steveax. I updated my answer.

Gremo, I'm not sure what you mean. The router *is* retrieving the data and serving the view -- all this is doing is letting the router react to link clicks. The query/view logic is still in the router, nothing more, nothing less.